# Python: Pass a "<" to Popen

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I want to start the testrunner.bat of ReadyApi with parameters. I try to pass some XML parts (PeriodEnd in the code below) as arguments to subprocess.Popen:

```
argslist = ['C:/Program Files/SmartBear/ReadyAPI-1.9.0/bin/testrunner.bat',
    '-a', '-s', 'TestSuite', '-c', 'TestCase', '-f', 'C:/temp/', '-P', 
    'PeriodEnd=<PeriodEnd>2017-04-11T00:00:00.000Z</PeriodEnd>', 
    'C:/temp/soapui-project.xml']
proc = Popen(argslist, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

This produces the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I found out, that the "<" and ">" are the problems. How can I escape them or pass them to Popen?

Comment: I'm guessing Windows would like for you to put double quotes around that particular argument, but I don't have a Wintendo box to test this on.

Comment: Did you try to run that command in CMD directly?

Comment: I also tried with '""PeriodEnd=<PeriodEnd>2017-04-11T00:00:00.000Z</PeriodEnd>""' but this did not help.

Comment: Yes I tried in CMD directly and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The escape character in CMD is `^`.

```
C:\> echo asdf<123>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\> echo asdf^<123^>
asdf<123>
```

Comment: Yes, subprocess `list2cmdline` uses VC++ rules for creating a command line. It doesn't know how to escape command lines for cmd.exe, especially considering they often have to be crafted to survive not only cmd but also the command-line parsing of whatever you're running via cmd. If you're using `Popen` to run a batch file directly or using `shell=True`, I recommend using a verified command-line string as opposed to an args list.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is used to escape character, try `\<`

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

possibly use `"` instead of the `'`

Comment: Angle brackets don't need escaped in Python. It's a Windows CMD problem